# C Generic Selection with two types

Tags: c, generics, c11

I want to use `C` Generic selection to infer the function by using two factors instead of only one.
Let's say I have this `C` file:

```
#define draw(X, Y) \
        _Generic((X), \
        struct circle: draw_circle, \
        struct square: draw_square \
        )(X, Y)

struct circle{};
struct square{};

void draw_circle_with_int(struct circle a, int i){}
void draw_circle_with_double(struct circle a, double d){}
void draw_square_with_int(struct square a, int i){}
void draw_sqaure_with_double(struct square a, double d){}

int main(void)
{
    struct circle c;
    /* draw(c, 3); */  // `draw_circle_with_int`
    /* draw(a, 3.5); */  // `draw_circle_with_double`

    struct square s;
    /* draw(s, 5); */  // `draw_square_with_int`
    /* draw(s, 5.5); */  // `draw_square_with_double`
}
```

In `draw(X, Y)`, `X` as well as `Y` should decide the function call. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: You should probably make those struct parameters `const struct type*` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a C11 compiler handy sorry so I could not test it, but perhaps you could try this:

```
#define draw(X, Y) \
        _Generic((X), \
            struct circle: _Generic((Y), \
                int: draw_circle_with_int, \
                double: draw_circle_with_double ), \
            struct square: _Generic((Y), \
                int: draw_square_with_int, \
                double: draw_square_with_double ) \
        )(X, Y)
```

Comment: I tried it out your answer, removed some commas and it worked. It's more straightforward than I thought it would be. I have edited your answer to make it correct.